Human fecal sample storage: Can it be stored temporarily at -20 C before being transferred to -80C deep freezer?
I am trying to analyze human gut microbial composition by 16S sequencing.
There is enough literature saying it is crucial and standard to store the sample at -80 C if it can't be processed in the molecular lab.
Can the hospital ward, that collects the samples, store the sample immediately at -20 C first which can then be transported to the lab on ice and then stored at -80 C ?
Literature also points out that the sample should not undergo more than 4-5 freeze-thaw cycles.
Experts and experienced, any kind of input would be helpful.
Thank you.
R

Welcome. I think it all depends on how long the samples are stored at temps above the recommended temp - can you clarify your question - what microorganisms are you interested in? How long will the samples be stored in -20? etc etc. In addition, we require questions to be accompanied by some evidence of finding a solution to the problem; what have you found so far? Lastly, provide links to the literature you have used as indicated in the post; please edit the question.

If maintaining bacterial viability is not a concern, I would recommend using a nucleic acid preservative like DNA/RNA shield or STAR buffer or RNALater. Some are sold pre-dispensed in specimen tubes with a scoop or swab for stool collection. They're all pretty great for maintaining the composition of the microbiota, but it depends on your storage conditions, specimen types, etc. Plus they tend to inactivate most pathogens, which has saved me some paperwork to do with shipping and receiving certain specimens in the past.
